# How to configure Apache2.4 with two locations

Tags: html, apache, virtual, host

I have an Ubuntu Server with a standard apache 2.4 installed that get its content from /var/www/html.
So every html page I have is accessed by http://example.com/index.html ...
Now i want a separate Directory /var/app1/html that holds another web-project and that can be accessed by http://example.com/application1/
I have tried to setup a different conf. file under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled with the following content

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/app1/html
    <Directory /var/app1/html>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However if I do not know how to setup the name application1 so that example.com/application1 links to /var/app1/html

Best regards

P0nch0

Answer (score 0):

I put both configurations in one conf file (Not sure if that will make a difference for you). You should be able to link app1 to the directory by changing the ServerName of app1 to include the path. For Instance:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/app1/html
    <Directory /var/app1/html>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com/app2
    ServerAlias www.example.com/app2
    DocumentRoot /var/app2/html
    <Directory /var/app2/html>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are wanting to connect to the app using any other domains on top of ServerName you should use ServerAlias. For instance:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com/app2
    ServerAlias example2.com www.example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/app2/html
    <Directory /var/app2/html>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It may be more beneficial to setup this configuration using subdomains instead: app2.example.com

Hope this helps!